# Parallax background image as a sliding carousel

Tags: javascript, carousel, parallax

I have been tinkering around with creating a parallax scrolling site over the last couple of days. I have a nice prototype working that scrolls different background images. Looks pretty cool.

I'd like to take it one step further. I basically have a div with a background image assigned to it. The background image scrolls at a different speed. I want to now add the ability to click a left or right arrow and change that background. Basically a carousel. But, I still want to maintain the parallax effect if the user scrolls down.

The structure of the HTML is:

```
<section id="one">
<div id="mainimagewrapper">
    <div class="image1">
        <div class="image2">
            <div id="textdiv">this is some text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The mainimagewrapper contains the large image that I want to change. The textdiv will be where I add my links to the next images.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js changes the background to a random one from the array:

```
function changeBG()
{
    var images = new Array('http://www.windows-7-wallpapers.com/wallpapers/img24-1920x1200.jpg',
                           'http://www.pptbackgroundstemplates.com/backgrounds/seamless-white-texture-ppt-backgrounds-powerpoint.jpg',
                          'http://awesomewallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/white2.png',
                          'http://www.wallpaperpimper.com/wallpaper/Flower/Flower_Art/Flower-Art-Winter-White-1-1920x1200.jpg');

    $('#mainimagewrapper').css("background-image", "url("+ images[getRandom(0, images.length - 1)] +")");
}




function getRandom(min, max) {
    if (min > max) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (min == max) {
        return min;
    }

    var r;

    //do {
    r = Math.random();
    //}
    //while (r == 1.0);

    return min + parseInt(r * (max - min + 1));
}
```

You can create your button like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeBG();" >
```

or like this:

```
<a href="javascript:changeBG();">ButtonText</a>
```

This should change de background-image to a random one of that 4 pictures...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am curious if this would still work because I'm using a div with an <a href> tag as my link and not an actual form button like you have shown.

Comment: Let me test this out today and I'll report back. Thanks.

Comment: well I was able to test this out. Unfortunately this isn't changing the background image. I removed my script for the parallax scrolling just to see if that was interfering, but it still wouldn't work. I threw your code into the head of my doc and dropped that link inside the #mainimagewrapper div. I'm stumped.

Comment: how do you define the background atm?

Comment: i forgot to copy the random function :3
would you try it again with the function ?

Comment: One thing I just thought of. How about changing to a specific background, not random, and being able to go forward or backward in a sequence? For example, say I have a next button and a prev button.